# React Native Animated, Complete Event

Tags: react-native

What's the best practice to trigger an event when Animated.spring finishes?

```
Animated.spring(this.state.pan, {
    toValue: 0
}).start()
```

I've searched quite a bit and haven't found a single way to do it. I could use addListener to check if the animation has reached it's end value or a timeout, but they both feel like ugly fixes to what should be super simple.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 306, accepted):

Half an hour of googling later and i found this, can't believe they didn't document this better.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3212

```
.start(callback)
```

Answer (score 32):

This will get fired at the start of the animation

```
.start(console.log("Start Animation")
```

Using an arrow function or function, done will get called at the **END** of the animation

```
.start(() => {console.log("Animation DONE")})
```

And finaly this is what it looks like in the context to of a function.

```
_play(){
  Animated.timing(this.state.progress, {
     toValue: 1,
     duration: 5000,
     easing: Easing.linear,
   }).start(() => {console.log("Animation DONE")});
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: `.start(console.log("Start Animation")` will only "fire" at the start of an animation because of a side effect. This is functionally the same as `console.log("Start Animation"); Animated.timing(...).start(..)`. This is not the intentional use of the method. Please do not use this. `start()` takes a callback for when the animation  finishes and that's all.

Comment: Could you loop the animation by calling the same function within this completion callback?

Comment: This isn't working for me, even though I add an arrow function inside start, the function is executed immediately for some reason

Comment: @NightTom Yes, you could. I am using it in my application exactly like this.

Answer (score 1):

Now there are docs for this: https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated#working-with-animations

The updated answer should be:

```
.start(({finished}) => {
    if (finished) {
        console.log('animation ended!)
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically there these three approaches to do something when an animation finishes.
First: you can use the callback passed into call(callback) method.
Second: You can use stopAnimation which also accepts a callback
Third: My preferred way,which consisting in placing a listener on the animated value,and do something based on the current value.
For example, you can make a translation from 0 to 150 and based on a value you animate, say 'motion' and when motion reaches a value you can perform something.

```
let motion = Animated.Value(0);

motion.addListener(({value}) =>{
  if(value>=10){
    pos.stopAnimation((val)=>{console.log('stopped in '+val)});
  }
});
```

More onhttps://www.youtube.com/channel/UCl5-W0A8tE3EucM7E_yS62A